# How to fetch a field from document using n1ql with spring-data-couchbase

Tags: sql++, spring-data-couchbase

This is the query in the repository which works fine.

```
public interface PlayerRepo extends CrudRepository<Player, String>{

@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE code = $1 and #{#n1ql.filter}")
public List<Player> findPlayersWithCode(String code);
}
```

I want to fetch specific field from Player document, like this:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity.name} WHERE code = $1 and #{#n1ql.filter}")
public List<String> findPlayerNamesWithCode(String code);
```

Is it possible to do this, I am using spring-data-couchbase 2.1.2

Comment: This feature would be really useful, seems like it is not possible atm but would be really nice to include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, this is not possible from a repository. Spring Data Hopper introduced a `Projection` feature that would allow it, but the Couchbase store implementation doesn't yet cover it.

There's something close in the `CouchbaseTemplate`, which has a `findByN1QLProjection` method, but it needs a DTO dedicated to the query. For example:

```
SELECT name, lastName FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE code = $1 AND #{#n1ql.filter}
```

which is equivalent (in pure N1QL) to:

```
SELECT name, lastName FROM bucketThatBacksRepository WHERE code = $1 AND _class = "com.example.Person"
```

would require the following class to work with `findByN1QLProjection`:

```
public class PersonNameDTO {
    private final String name;
    private final String lastName;

    //constructor and maybe getters/setters needed but omitted here
}
```

And it would produce a `List<PersonNameDTO>`. Note that this is not hugely different from the projection feature I was talking about, except it's designed around interfaces rather than concrete DTO classes.

Note that you shouldn't use the `#{#n1ql.selectEntity}` SpEL since its purpose is to have a large SELECT clause that covers all the fields of a given entity (whereas here you want to restrict the SELECT clause).

It also covers the FROM part with the correct bucket associated to your repository, but the `#{#n1ql.bucket}` also covers that part (and that part only)...

Comment: According to me it is possible using Couchbase, i can execute queries like select subDocumentField FROM `my-bucket` where meta().id = 'my-id'. So it is just that spring data couchbase doesn't support it... A confirmation from a more experimented user would be nice :).

Comment: This will be possible in the version shipped with Spring Data Ingalls, couchbase connector will then support spring data projections