# Spring data Couchbase #n1ql.fields query

Tags: couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to make a N1QL based query on Spring Data Couchbase. The documentation says

> #n1ql.fields will be replaced by the list of fields (eg. for a SELECT clause) necessary to reconstruct the entity.

My repository implementation is this one:

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.fields} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
List<User> findAllByFields(String fields);
```

And I'm calling this query as follows:

```
this.userRepository.findAllByFields("SELECT firstName FROM default");
```

I'm getting this error:

> Caused by: org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException: Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors: 
>   {"msg":"syntax error - at AS","code":3000}

After a little bit of researching, I also tryed:

```
@Query("SELECT #{#n1ql.fields} FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
```

With this query, I don't get an error, I get all the documents stored but only the ID the other fields are set to null, when my query tries to get the firstName field.

```
 this.userRepository.findAllByFields("firstName");
```

Anyone knows how to do such a query?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the concept, I encourage you to give the documentation more time and see more examples. I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but I'll throw some examples.

**Find all users (with all of their stored data)**

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
List<User> findAllUsers();
```

This will basically generate `SELECT meta().id,_cas,* FROM bucket WHERE type='com.example.User'`

Notice `findAllUsers()` does not take any parameters because there are no param placeholders defined in the `@Query` above.

**Find all users where firstName like**

```
@Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND firstName like $1")
List<User> findByFirstNameLike(String keyword);
```

This will generate something like the above query but with an extra where condition `firstName like`

Notice this method takes a keyword because there is a param placeholder defined `$1`.

---

Notice in the documentation it says

> #{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter} AND test = $1
>
> is equivalent to
>
> SELECT #{#n1ql.fields} FROM #{#n1ql.bucket} WHERE
> #{#n1ql.filter} AND test = $1

---

Now if you don't want to fetch all the data for user(s), you'll need to specify the fields being selected, read following links for more info

[How to fetch a field from document using n1ql with spring-data-couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478291/how-to-fetch-a-field-from-document-using-n1ql-with-spring-data-couchbase)

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_dto_projections

Comment: The documentation you posted it helped me a lot. Finally I understood Spring Data doesn't support it and the only option is to use projections. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try below query, that should resolve the issue to get fields based parameter you have sent as arguments.

Please refer blow query.

@Query("SELECT $1 FROM #{#n1q1.bucket} WHERE #{#n1ql.filter}")
List findByFirstName(String fieldName);

Here, bucket name resolve to the User entity and and n1ql.filter would be a default filter.