# How to correctly do single field n1ql projections with spring-data-couchbase

Tags: sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to project a single field in a document. I tried a couple of approaches - one mentioned here in this [Spring data Couchbase doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#_dto_projections) and another mentioned in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38479557/3441543)

All of it returns the same exception

```
org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseQueryExecutionException:    
Unable to execute query due to the following n1ql errors: {"msg":"Ambiguous reference to field _class.","code":3000}
    at org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.CouchbaseTemplate.findByN1QL(CouchbaseTemplate.java:458) ~[spring-data-couchbase-3.0.6.RELEASE.jar:3.0.6.RELEASE]
```

Below is the query that I am using and it runs as expected on the `Query workbench`

```
public interface ProjectRespository extends CouchbasePagingAndSortingRepository<Project, String> {

     @Query("SELECT DISTINCT projectId where #{#n1ql.filter} AND serverTech = $1")   
      List<ProjectIdDTO> findByServerTech(@Param("serverTech") String serverTech);
```

`ProjectIdDTO` is a DTO I have specifically defined to return a List of ProjectId's. Not sure what is that I am missing here.

Comment: Looks like FROM clause is missing in the query

Comment: As mentioned by @vsr , it also needs FROM #{#n1ql.bucket}

Comment: When I try this I get the error `Unable to retrieve enough metadata for N1QL to entity mapping, have you selected _ID and _CAS?`... did you have to do anything special in the DTO class?

Comment: @snoopDoug Yes, you need to fetch the ID & CAS in addition to what you are projecting. Check this -  https://forums.couchbase.com/t/custom-n1ql-query-with-couchbase-and-spring-boot/18233

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @vsr @subhashni for pointing out. Trivial mistake. It was indeed the missing #{n1ql.bucket} that was causing the error.

The `Ambiguous reference to field _class` should have prompted me to double-check the query.