# How to return a boolean from a document using spring-data-couchbase with @Query

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase, sql++, spring-data-couchbase

I am using spring-data-couchbase 4.1.1. I want to add a method in my repository method like following

```
public interface DomainRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Domain, String> {

@Query(("SELECT isActive from #{#n1ql.bucket}  "
      + "WHERE META().id = " + "\"#{#id}\" "))
Boolean isActive(@Param("id") String id);

}
```

But it throws ClassCastException for Domain to Boolean which is acceptable I believe.

Is there any other simple way to do it? I believe there was a findByN1QlProjection in older version of couchbaseTemplate, can't find it in this version though. But I rather not use couchbasetemplate directly or sub-document apis of couchbase sdk.

A similar older question [How to fetch a field from document using n1ql with spring-data-couchbase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478291/how-to-fetch-a-field-from-document-using-n1ql-with-spring-data-couchbase)

Answer (score 1):

A proposed solution is to define a DTO and its repository specifically for fields one wants.

```
class IsActiveDTO {

private isActive;

// constructor, getters, and setters
}
```

and define its repository

```
public interface IsActiveDTORepository extends CouchbaseRepository<IsActiveDTO, String> {

@Query(("SELECT isActive from #{#n1ql.bucket}  "
      + "WHERE META().id = " + "\"#{#id}\" "))
IsActiveDTO isActive(@Param("id") String id);

}
```